# C++ Nested class in class template declaration

Tags: class, templates, c++11, nested

I'm attempting to write a C++11 linked list implementation, with the linked list being a template class and its node being a nested class as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    class Node;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> listSearch(const T &input) const;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> tail;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList<T>::Node {
private:
    T data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
}
```

I am assuming that the class Node is not a template in itself, but when LinkedList gets instantiated it creates the Node class as well.

When I attempt to define the listSearch function as follows, I get an error: "template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?". Can someone explain what is wrong?

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<LinkedList<T>::Node> LinkedList<T>::listSearch(const T &input) { ... }
```

Edit:

Ok, so I recompiled with gcc and the error message was clearer. It wants the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<typename LinkedList<T>::Node> LinkedList<T>::listSearch(const T &input) const { ... }
```

Why is the typename necessary before LinkedList::Node? Isn't it obvious that it's a type?

Comment: forgot to put `template <typename T>`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. template <typename T> is present, just forgot to add it in the question. Edited the OP.

Comment: I put a link in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<typename LinkedList<T>::Node> LinkedList<T>::listSearch(const T &input) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah C++ you are so complex. Thanks, that answers my question.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types Another answer for anyone interested.

Comment: I have a question: what if I want to implement Node seperatedly? I mean, outside of current file?